# Find $\int_{|z| = 1}\left(\frac{z}{z - a}\right)^ndz$ — Is my solution correct?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following complex integral for the case $|a| < 1$, $n > 1$:
$$
\int_{|z| = 1}\left(\frac{z}{z - a}\right)^ndz
$$

My attempt:

$z^n$ is an entire function. I define 
$$\varphi(w) := \int_{|z| = 1}\frac{z^n}{z - w}dz$$ 
So $\varphi(w) = 2\pi i w^n$ by Cauchy's theorem.

Now we know that $\varphi^{(n)}\in Hol(\mathbb{C} \setminus \{|z| = 1\})$ and:
$$
\varphi^{(n)}(w) = n! \int_{|z| = 1} \frac{z^n}{(z - w)^{n+1}}dz
$$

Putting it all together, I get:
$$
\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{z^n}{(z - w)^{n}}dz = \frac{1}{n!}(2 \pi i w^n)^{n - 1} = 2 \pi i w
$$

So I get $2 \pi i a$ for the integral.

Does this make sense?

**Edit:** $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: $z^n=e^{n\log z}$ is NOT an entire function! It's holomorphic only on the slit plane $\mathbb C_-=\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R_-$ (if we choose the principal brach of the logarithm).

Comment: @Joe $n$ is probably an integer.

Comment: @DanielFischer: yes but... what does change? $n^z=e^{z\log n}$ is an entire function (when $n\in\mathbb N$), $z^n$ not, since it's equal to $e^{n\log z}$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Joe $z\mapsto z^n$ is an entire function for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. It is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $n < 0$. $z\mapsto a^z$ is entire for every $a\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, for every choice of the branch (of the logarithm of $a$).

Comment: Your last displayed equation should be $$
\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{z^n}{(z - w)^{n}}dz = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}(2 \pi i w^n)^{(n - 1)} = 2 \pi i n w.
$$ And yes, this is assuming $n$ is an integer.

Comment: @DanielFischer: how can $z\mapsto z^n$ can be holomorphic on $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$? $z^n=e^{n\log z}$ and since $\log z$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C_-$, it should follow that $z\mapsto z^n$ can't be holomorphic in a region that contains strictly $\mathbb C_-$. What is wrong in my argument?

Comment: @Joe If you go the $e^{n\log z}$ route, we have holomorphic branches of $\log$ in a neighbourhood of any $z\neq 0$, and any two branches differ by a multiple of $2\pi i$. So for the corresponding branches of $z^n$, we have $e^{n(\log z + 2k\pi i)} = e^{n\log z} e^{2nk\pi i} = e^{n\log z}$, since $e^{2nk\pi i} = 1$. More elementarily, $z^0 \equiv 1$, and $z^{n+1} = z\cdot z^n$ for positive integers, and $z^n = \frac{1}{z^{\lvert n\rvert}}$ for negative integers and $z\neq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $n$ is supposed to be an integer, the idea is right, but there are a few glitches in the execution.

1. $\varphi(w) = 2\pi i w^n$ only holds for $\lvert w\rvert < 1$, on $\{ w : \lvert w\rvert > 1\}$, we have $\varphi(w)\equiv 0$. It is best to consider $\varphi$ only for $\lvert w\rvert < 1$. This is mostly cosmetic, however.
2. $\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{z^n}{(z-w)^n}\,dz = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\varphi^{(n-1)}(w)$ by the formula for the derivatives of $\varphi$ you got. You wrote that it were $\frac{1}{n!}(2\pi iw^n)^{n-1}$. I suppose writing the $^{(n-1)}$ without parentheses, like an exponent is a glitch. But, using a parenthesised superscript on an expression to indicate a $k$-th derivative is unusual at best, and easily confusing. Better write $\varphi^{(n-1)}(w)$ or $\frac{d^n}{dw^n}(2\pi iw^n)$, these notations are more common. Having the wrong factor, $\frac{1}{n!}$ instead of $\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$, is an error in the matter, probably induced from writing $$\varphi^{(n)}(w) = n!\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{z^n}{(z-w)^{n+1}}\,dz$$ using the same letter for the fixed parameter $n$ from the task and for the order of the derivative. Had you written $$\varphi^{(k)}(w) = k! \int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{z^n}{(z-w)^k}\,dz,$$ such a mistake would have been less likely.

Additional sanity check:

$$z^n = ((z-a)+a)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (z-a)^{n-k}a^k,$$

and we need the term containing the power $(z-a)^{n-1}$, since all others integrate to $0$.

Comment: I would have voted up your answer several times if I could - I always make this type of mistakes *sigh*. Thanks!